# preg_replace to match all but first occurance of something?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm looking for a way to replace all but first occurrences of a group or some character.

For example a following random string:

```
+Z1A124B555ND124AB+A555
```

1,5,2,4,A,B and + are repeating through out the string.

124, 555 are groups of characters that are also reoccurring.

Now, let's say I want to remove every but first occurrence of 555, A and B.

What regex would be appropriate? I could think of an example replacing all:

```
preg_replace('/555|A|B/','',$string);
```

Something like ^ that, but I want to keep the first occurrence... Any ideas?

Comment: You could split at `+`, run the regex on everything but the first array element and then join the replaced strings to a single string

Comment: I don't quite understand your vision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Are your strings always delimited by plus signs? Do 555, A, and B always occur in the first "group" (delimited by +)?</s>

If so, you can split, replace and then join:

```
$input = '+Z1A124B555+A124AB+A555';
$array = explode('+', $input, 3); // max 3 elements
$array[2] = str_replace(array('555', 'A', 'B'), '', $array[2]);
$output = implode('+', $array);
```

ps. No need to use regexes, when we can use a simple str_replace

---

Use the [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) function:

```
$replaced = array('555' => 0, 'A' => 0, 'B' => 0);
$input = '+Z1A124B555+A124AB+A555';
$output = preg_replace_callback('/555|[AB]/', function($matches) {
  static $replaced = 0;
  if($replaced++ == 0) return $matches[0];
  return '';
}, $input);
```

Comment: No, that wasn't the case... there are no delimiters at all, it's just a random occurrence, which is completely random... I will try to edit my example to make it a little more clear.

Comment: Cool, that's a nice idea to store the number of matches in $replaced, so I guess I will stick with it! Thanks.

Comment: I just wonder, if it's ok to use $match, since it may return array. My php also whines about illegal offset type on line 4 of your code. I'll try to figure it out first :-) Though yes, it looks definitely doable .that way/

Comment: Okay, my bad. `$match` is actually an array. The complete match is stored in `$match[0]`. I'll update my answer

Comment: Yep, thanks, it works now ^.^ or... wait, it doesn't :D I'm also trying to figure it out what's wrong.

Comment: I guess I found it.. it should use global $replace inside inside the func.

Answer (score 1):

This solution could be modified to do what you want: [PHP: preg_replace (x) occurrence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519630/php-preg-replace-x-occurence)

Here is a modified solution for you:

```
<?php
class Parser {

    private $i;

    public function parse($source) {
        $this->i=array();
        return preg_replace_callback('/555|A|B/', array($this, 'on_match'), $source);
    }

    private function on_match($m) {
        $first=$m[0];
        if(!isset($this->i[$first]))
        {
            echo "I'm HERE";
            $this->i[$first]=1;
        }
        else
        {

            $this->i[$first]++;
        }
        

        
        // Return what you want the replacement to be.
        if($this->i[$first]>1)
        {
            $result="";
        }
        else
        {
            $result=$m[0];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

$sample = '+Z1A124B555ND124AB+A555';
$parse = new Parser();
$result = $parse->parse($sample);
echo "Result is: [$result]\n";
?>
```

Comment: Yep it works :) It's exactly the same solution just made into a class though. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic function that works with every pattern.

```
function replaceAllButFirst($pattern, $replacement, $subject) {

  return preg_replace_callback($pattern,

    function($matches) use ($replacement, $subject) {
      static $s;
      $s++;
      return ($s <= 1) ? $matches[0] : $replacement;
    },

    $subject
  );
}
```