# Replacing by preg_replace only if there is more matches

Tags: php, preg-replace, expression

I want to replace text only if there is more than 1 matching text. If there's one matching element, I don't want to replace. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure. Use `preg_match_all` make make sure that `count($matches[1])` is greater than or equal to `2`.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519630/php-preg-replace-x-occurence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$subject = 'This is the text in which we will perform replacements';
$pattern = '/\si[ns]\s/';
$replace = ' XX ';

if( preg_match_all( $pattern , $subject , $matches )
    && isset( $matches[0] )
    && count( $matches[0] )>=2 ){

  $subject = preg_replace( $pattern , $replace , $subject );

}else{

  #echo 'Not Enough Matches';

}
```

(Will replace " in " and " is " with " XX ".)