# preg_replace() replace second occurrence

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

This is what I do now:

```
if (strpos($routeName,'/nl/') !== false) {
    $routeName = preg_replace('/nl/', $lang , $routeName, 1 );
}
```

I replace the `nl` with for ex. `de` . But now I want to replace the `second occurrence`. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: preg_replace does replace all occurences of `/nl/` with `$lang` if used right. Why don't you just repeart your code if you want to replace the second occurence?
Maybe read the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: use pregmatch it returns an array of matches , then use str_replace for the second element in the array

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: preg\_replace (x) occurence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519630/php-preg-replace-x-occurence)

Comment: You may also check [this](https://vijayasankarn.wordpress.com/2017/01/03/string-replace-nth-occurrence-php/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So firstly you check if there is any occurrence and if so, you replace it.
You could count the occurrences (*unsing [substr_count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)*) instead to know how many of them exist.
Then, just replace them bit by bit if that's what you need.

```
$occurrences = substr_count($routeName, '/nl/');
if ($occurrences > 0) {
  $routeName = preg_replace('/nl/', $lang , $routeName, 1 );
  if ($occurrences > 1) {  
    // second replace
    $routeName = preg_replace('/nl/', $lang , $routeName, 1 );
  }
}
```

If you only want to replace the second occurrence (*as stated by you later on in the comments*), check out [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and read up on [string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php) in PHP.
You can use the first occurrence, found using `strpos` as a start for substr and just use that for your replacement.

```
<?php

$routeName = 'http://example.nl/language/nl/peter-list/foo/bar?example=y23&source=nl';
$lang = 'de';

$routeNamePart1 = substr( $routeName, 0 , strpos($routeName,'nl') +4 );
$routeNamePart2 = substr( $routeName, strpos($routeName,'nl') + 4);
$routeNamePart2 = preg_replace('/nl/', $lang , $routeNamePart2, 1 );
$routeName = $routeNamePart1 . $routeNamePart2;

echo $routeName;
```

See this working [here](https://eval.in/140208).

Answer (score 15):

The answer by @Casimir seems rather applicable to most cases. Another alternative is [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) with a counter. In case you need a specific n-th occurence to be replaced only.

```
#-- regex-replace an occurence by count
$s = "…abc…abc…abc…";
$counter = 1;
$s = preg_replace_callback("/abc/", function ($m) use (&$counter) {

     #-- replacement for 2nd occurence of "abc"
     if ($counter++ == 2) {
          return "def";
     }

     #-- else leave current match
     return $m[0];

}, $s);
```

This utilizes a local `$counter`, incremented within the callback on each occurence, and there simply checked for a fixed position here.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that:

```
$lang = 'de'
$routeName = preg_replace('~/nl/.*?(?<=/)\Knl/~', "$lang/", $routeName, 1 );
```

`\K` will remove all on the left from match result.*(Thus, all that has been matched on the left with by `/nl/.*?(?<=/)` will not be replaced.)*

I use a lookbehind `(?<=/)` instead of a literal `/` to deal with this specific case `/nl/nl/` *(In this case `.*?` matches an empty substring.)*