# preg replace second substring occurence in url

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to remove the second occurrence of a substring from an url. So, my urls are something like this:

```
http://example.com/<category>/<category>-<subcategory>-<id>
```

e.g.

```
http://example.com/laptop/laptop-hp-probook-101 must be http://example.com/laptop/hp-probook-101
```

or

```
http://example.com/computer-parts/computer-parts-cool-motherboard-123 must be http://example.com/computer-parts/cool-motherboard-123
```

I tried this:

```
$new_url = preg_replace("$category", "", absoluteurl(<url>), 1);
```

but it fails...

Comment: it would help if you mentioned what pattern `$category` is

Comment: possible duplicate of [preg\_replace() replace second occurrence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239061/preg-replace-replace-second-occurrence)

Comment: $category can be 'laptop', 'computer-parts' etc.

Comment: Why you use "$category" in "" and not just $category ?

Comment: so you don't have any delimiters in your pattern? you should probably consult the preg_replace manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a backreference:

```
<?php
$str = 'http://example.com/laptop/laptop-hp-probook-101';
//must be http://example.com/laptop/hp-probook-101
$str = preg_replace('/\/(.*?)\/\1-/', '/$1/', $str);
print $str;
```

Output:

`http://example.com/laptop/hp-probook-101`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 

$text = 'This is a test';

echo substr_count($text, 'is'); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url='https://www.yourdomain.com/laptops/laptops-hp-laptop-laptopid';
$arr1=explode("://",$url);
$arr2=explode("/",$arr1[1]);
$arr2[2]=str_replace ( $arr2[1]."-" , "" , $arr2[2] );
$s2=implode("/",$arr2);
$newurl=$arr1[0]."://".$s2;
echo $newurl;
```

you can try all of the above here http://writecodeonline.com/php/