# PHP Replace second occurence of ? with an &

Tags: php

I have few strings, if the string is as below

```
$string ="w?w+f=w?wefwef?blahblah";

$desiredString ="w?w+f=w&wefwef?blahblah";
```

If this format, I am trying to replace second ? to & else do nothing.

I've tried regex and preg_match but no luck.

Comment: Why have you ended up with that string to begin with? It is usually best to fix stuff like this where it actually happens, and not patch it up after the fact.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239061/preg-replace-replace-second-occurrence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your current case solution is:

```
$string ="w?w+f=w?wefwef?blahblah";

$desiredString = preg_replace('/^(.+?\?.+?)\?/', '$1&', $string);

echo $desiredString;
```

Output:

```
w?w+f=w&wefwef?blahblah
```

N-th occurence RegExp:

```
/^((?:(?:.*?\?){0}.*?))\?/ // for first occurence
/^((?:(?:.*?\?){1}.*?))\?/ // for second occurence
/^((?:(?:.*?\?){2}.*?))\?/ // for third occurence
                           // etc.
```

Comment: Wow! single line regex. But may I know how to use if I want to replace nth instance in it?

Comment: @kennyben what is problem you are facing? have you checked my answer?

Comment: @Thamilan thank you for your help, i found my mistake. this solution is working well now.

Comment: @kennyben view updated answer with first occurence support.

Comment: Not working for me when the string starts with `?` like this `$string ="?w+f=w?wefwef?blahblah";` I couldn't replace first `?`

Comment: @Thamilan it's a little another case.

Comment: I want to replace your regex in my utility function, but it was excellent for the rest until a string started with

Comment: @Thamilan use updated RegExp. Also you can remove `?:` form it.

Comment: Thank you! I tried removing instead of replacing * with +! Great work !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string ="w?w+f=w?wefwef?blahblah";
$desiredString = '';
$j = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
    if($string[$i] == '?' && ++$j == 2)
        $desiredString .= '&';
    else
        $desiredString .= $string[$i];
}

echo $desiredString; //w?w+f=w&wefwef?blahblah
```