# How to I show the featured image in paragraph two or three?

Tags: php, regex

This code helps me place the featured image after paragraph one. How would I use it to place the same image in another paragraph, say paragraph two or three?

```
// Adds $img content after after first paragraph (!.e. after first `</p>` tag)
add_filter('the_content', function($content)
    {
       $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
       $img = '<img src="'.$url.'" alt="" title=""/>';
       $content = preg_replace('#(<p>.*?</p>)#','$1' .$img, $content, 1);
       return $content;
    });
```

Comment: Perphaps this page can be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239061/preg-replace-replace-second-occurrence

Comment: @alba we need a larger and more realistic sample of your valid html document so that we can offer an answer that is better than regex.  your question should have a [mcve].  You should only be using a legitimate DOM parser (php offers these natively) to parse valid html.  Please [edit] your question so that you can receive a resolution.